# Scrollbar-Button jitters when reaching maximum/minimum

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll, position, scrollbar

I'm building a scrollbar.

On MouseDown I start a repeating timer to position the Scrollbar-Button(Slider).
When it reaches minimum/maximum it jitters (switching between min/max and stage.mouseY…)
How can I prevent that?

```
private function onTime(e:TimerEvent):void
    {

        if(this._scrollBtn.y < min)
        {
            this._scrollBtn.y = min;
        }
        else if(this._scrollBtn.y > max-this._scrollBtn.height)
        {
            this._scrollBtn.y = max-this._scrollBtn.height;
        }
        else
        {
            this._scrollBtn.y = stage.mouseY;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend listening for the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` instead of using a timer, that way you're only doing work if and when the mouse is moving.

Your problem is likely that your validating the position of the scroll handle "after" moving it, letting it be out of bounds for a while before the next update comes and moves it back.

There's also no reason in having `this` everywhere, unless it's explicitly needed.

```
private function onTime(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    _scrollBtn.y = stage.mouseY;

    if(_scrollBtn.y < min)
    {
        _scrollBtn.y = min;
    }
    else if(_scrollBtn.y > max - _scrollBtn.height)
    {
        _scrollBtn.y = max - _scrollBtn.height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! According "this": I'm using it to have an additional marker to recognize class-variables faster... Are there any drawbacks in your opinion?

Comment: I don't think there's any runtime speed to gain by doing that, and since I assume the _underscore means it's a private variable it only really means more typing for you. But, in the end it's a matter of taste, so do whatever you feel is best!